# connect via socket with a button

Tags: android, sockets, button, android-activity

are days that I'm stuck with this problem. I created an application with the fragment and tabs, I have to insert a button that when clicked connects to a certain ip and to a certain port, I have no idea how to write and how to put it, they are only able to connect when it starts mainActivity, but I wish it were possible to control it by a button, can you help?

Comment: what happens after connecting to ip by socket

Comment: if I can not connect to send and receive data at the end with another button to turn off the connection. for now, it crashes and does not connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could, I changed the line of code
from:

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(InetSocketAddress... params) {

        InetSocketAddress addr = params[0];

        try {
            **socket = new Socket(addr.getAddress().toString(), addr.getPort());**
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

to

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(InetSocketAddress... params) {

        InetSocketAddress addr = params[0];

        try {
            **socket = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 80);**
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

First, with last versions of Android framework all network operations can't be performed from the main thread (ie the thread that manage the UI). So, you need to use your own thread to make the connection.

An example:

```
package it.resis.solarapp.activities.fourcloud.application;

import it.resis.solarapp.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CopyOfActivity4CloudConfiguration extends Activity {

    private volatile Socket socket = null;
    private boolean connectionOk = false;
    private Button buttonDisconnect;
    private Button buttonConnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        buttonConnect = findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.1", 80);
                new ConnectToIpTask().execute(addr);
            }
        });

        buttonDisconnect = findViewById(R.id.buttonDisconnect);
        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new CloseSocket().execute();
            }
        });

        buttonDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
        buttonConnect.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private class ConnectToIpTask extends AsyncTask<InetSocketAddress, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(InetSocketAddress... params) {

            InetSocketAddress addr = params[0];

            try {
                socket = new Socket(addr.getAddress().toString(), addr.getPort());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            connectionOk = result;

            // update here the ui with result
            if (result) {
                buttonDisconnect.setEnabled(true);
                buttonConnect.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private class CloseSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            buttonDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
            buttonConnect.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and unfortunately it does not work, the phone does not seem to connect. And the pulstante "disconnect" remains disabled.

Comment: I do not know if it matters but eclipse has forced me to change the lines of code by adding the buttons (Button)
example: buttonDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);